# Theming of custom block is not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I've been following this post

http://legomenon.io/article/drupal-7-creating-theming-custom-block-content

so i made them accordingly,

i have these, btw name my my custom module is **efq_story_list**

**HOOK_THEME**

```
function efq_story_list_theme() {
  return array(
    'efq_story_list_function_items' => array(
       'variables' => array('items' => NULL),
       'template' => 'templates/efq_story_list--block'
    ),
  );
}
```

**FUNCTION GENERATING THE LIST**

```
function __efq_story_list_block_content() {
   #SOME CODE HERE and variable $items has the list
   return theme("efq_story_list_function_items", array("items" => $items));
}
```

**HOOK_BLOCK_VIEW**

The name of the block is `opinion`

```
function efq_story_list_block_view($delta = ''){
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'opinion':
        $block['content'] = __efq_story_list_block_content();
        break;
  } 
  return $block;
}
```

Then on my `templates/efq_story_list--block` i have the file `efq_story_list--block.tpl.php`.. then i flush all the cache,

but now I get WSOD. I tried this in local machine and its working, so I am wondering what else can I miss in my production site.. Thank you very much.. I am quite new to drupal so I dont know where to look anymore...

**EDIT # 1**

the content of the template file is

```
<?php $items = $variables['items']; ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 news_list panel">
            <div class='thumbnail_wrapper'>
                <a href="<?php print render($item['path']); ?>"><img src="print render($item['image_url']);" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="meta small_sprite">
                <span class="generic icon source_<?php print render($item['source_class']); ?>"></span>
                <span><?php print render($item['source']); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="<?php print render($item['path']); ?>"><?php print render($item['title']); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of you template file? Is it overridden in the theme?

Comment: @SebCorbin i think not? and even if it is overridden why would i receive an wsod? shouldnt i get at least jut a warning/notice and the page will still load?

Comment: Is there a difference of PHP versions between your dev and prod environments? I'd say the <?php $items = $variables['items']; ?> is a bug and should not be there

Comment: Turn error reporting and debugging on dude. php.ini error reporting. And I'm agreed that <?php $items = $variables['items']; ?> should not be there. You're not even calling $items later!?!? Maybe that page you're reading off isn't the best and you should find something else :)

Comment: @klidifia i used `$items` in the foreach loop.. `$items = $variables['items']` is just passing the value, isnt it? i tried looking at the `dblog` but it does not give me any errors too.. PHP version are the same in my local and in the production, im just wondering maybe there are some complications in other modules installed in the prodcution. which i could know because i am new to the team and the prod site are like there for quite a while now... are there any methods that complicates with the `hook_theme` method? thanks guys for your initial response